# Parse csv file and for each object set as a variable

Tags: linux, bash, csv

What I'm trying to do is parse a `csv` file that has server names and ipaddresses and assign these to variables I then run commands using each set of variables.

So if the `cvs` file, `test.csv`, looks like this:

```
servername, ip address
alphaserver, 192.168.1.2
betaserver, 192.168.1.3
```

... and so on

How would I parse that out to make `$server1=alphaserver $ipaddress1=192.168.1.2` for each line?

Example of where I'm at:

```
INPUT=test.cvs IFS=, [ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; } while read "server name" "IP Address" do echo "Server name : $servername" echo "IP Address : $ipaddress"
```

Comment: Welcome!  While we will help with scripting, we are not a script writing service.  What have you got/tried so far?  Where are you getting stuck exactly?

Comment: Where I'm stuck is that I know I can use: 

INPUT=test.cvs
IFS=,
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read "server name" "IP Address"
do
 echo "Server name : $servername"
 echo "IP Address : $ipaddress"
done

How do I increment and for each line use those variables to perform tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I got it. Just stay in the while group. Get the variables and then after they are set do whatever pertaining to those, Like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=","
while read f1 f2
do
echo "Server name : $f1"
echo "IP Address : $f2"
servername=$f1
ipaddress=$f2

echo "Servername variable: $servername"
echo "IP address variable: $ipaddress"
# Insert whatever you need to do with those variables and then the
# while loop will move on to the next line and do that same thing.

done < test.csv
```

Comment: You still have to skip the first line with the headers.  Maybe you can find interesting the use of `tail -n +2` ;)